# Can we use flask-pyctuator to monitor Flask App with out using spring boot

Tags: python, spring-boot-actuator

I want to determine whether if python packages can be used to implement monitoring actuator /health endpoint . Our services are deployed on to Kubernetes and logs are logged in splunk and Kubernetes is monitores using splunk observability

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about using the actuator/health endpoint for k8s readiness-probe, or are you asking if there's an admin tool written in python that can monitor your application via the [Pyctuator](https://github.com/SolarEdgeTech/pyctuator) API.

Will try to answer both:

1. [Pyctuator](https://github.com/SolarEdgeTech/pyctuator) is adding APIs to your Flask app (and other popular frameworks). These APIs are providing many details about your application in a way that's compatible with Codecentric's "Spring Boot Admin". I'm not familiar with other admin-tools that can consume the actuator/pyctuator API. Also, Spring Boot Admin is great for monitoring Python services that use Pyctuator.
2. If you are looking for endpoint for k8s readiness probe, this can be cool if you have dependencies such as DB connection that you don't want your pod to be ready until the connection is up.